# Probability of choose at least 1 dirty dish

Tags: probability

I have this exercise:

> In a box there are 15 dishes and 3 are taken at random. If one in
>   three dishes have spots, what is the probability that at least one of
>   the dishes removed has spots?

My attempt was:

I need the probability that at least $1$ dish has spots, that is equal to $1 - P(N)$ where $P(N)$ is the probability of the three dishes  don't have spots.

Then, $P(N) = (\frac{2}{3})^3 = 8/27$. Therefore the probability $ 1 - P(N) $ is equal to $19/27$

But according to the guide the correct answer must be $67/91$. What is wrong with my development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the probability is $1-P(N)$. Let's calculate $P(N)$. The probability of choosing 1 clean dish is $P_1=10/15$ (as $5$ dishes have spots). Then the next dish has $P_2=9/14$ as there are $9$ clean dishes and $14$ total remaining. The last has $P_3=8/13$. So $P(N)=P_1\cdot P_2\cdot P_3=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8}{15\cdot14\cdot13}=\frac{720}{2730}=\frac{24}{91}$. Thus, $1-P(N)=67/91$.

Comment: Of couse,once you take out the dish, it doesn't come back, that was my mistake.